# GCE snapshot - no system state saved?

Tags: process, google-cloud-platform, snapshot

Being relatively new to GCE, but not to other virtualization tools like VmWare or VirtuaBox, I'm not able to find in GCE a concrete way to get a full snapshot of a live machine.
I'm guessing it's my fault or poor knowledge, but really GCE doesn't saves the "system state", or else dumps memory to snapshot?
I'd found many scripts and examples on how to flush buffers to disks before I create the snapshot, but no way to obtain a complete state of the machine, including what the machine itself is running at THAT point.
Let me say that, if this is correct, the GCE snapshot IS NOT a snapshot.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's a [VM image](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/images#what_are_images), not a snapshot, and it does not include the contents of RAM or the processor state. A [snapshot](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/disks/create-snapshots) is a point-in-time copy of a [persistent disk](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/disks/#pdspecs).

Comment: Thanks, Jarmod, but I don't agree.
I've been wandering through the Google online documentation for some days before I posted the question here, I know enough about flushing cache to gain a consistent disk, but it's not the point.

On whichever local virtual machine player you can freeze the state of a machine, no matter what O.S., with the running processes included.
While on the restore you can bring back the state of the machine, build another or do whatsoever, having a consistent running server at that Point in Time.
Thats what is called Snapshot.

Comment: In the cloud world I'm still gathering informations, but surely the service offered by VmWare in cloud can operate just like a local virtualized VmWare system.
I know that for GCE SQL approach can offer consistency and point-in-time restore for the database itself [link] (https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/backup-recovery) but this works exactely for a DB machine.
Not for all the systems.
I'm looking forward for someone who's been facing this approach in the past and actually is in charge to evaluate Cloud vendor offers by tipology.

In any case thanks again.

Comment: Let me also add, that a VM Image is useful if you need to clone and rebuild numerous VM one equal to the other, although in that case too you don't save the running processes.

Comment: I'm  not aware of a cloud that supports instance freeze/thaw. They're typically stop/start which is essentially shutdown/boot.

Comment: Sorry man, it seems we are never in line, but don't take it as a dislike.
As said above, Vcloud does it [link] (http://blogs.vmware.com/vsphere/2012/10/snapshots-with-vcloud-director-5-1.html)
Let me say that I do not work for VmWare, rather I work for a reseller of GCE services (that's why I'm looking for a chance to replicate a service like that in GCE).

Answer (score 0):

[link] (http://vcloud.vmware.com/uk/using-vcloud-air/tutorials/working-with-snapshots)

Here's an example of a cloud platform saving true snapshots, portraits of a specific second of a working machine.

Let me add a thought: 
I don't know if VCloud is considering a particular state, gains privileged access to disks for a limited time, avoiding contingency, or else does a temporary duplication of the working disk in another volume.
I'm still reading around, trying to get INTO the problem.
BUT... it dumps memory to snapshot.
This is the point, and I'm wondering why this seems to be not possible in GCE.